# Utility to Synchronize File Creation Date with Modified Date, Preferably Context Menu Capable for File Explorer

Tags: windows, command-line, windows-explorer, sync, context-menu

I'm annoyed when I copy files and the creation date is made new. I know that's technically true, the file is copied so its creation date gets changed, but when the modified date of the copy is still the original file's creation date (the file that a copy was made of), I'd like to be able to update the creation date of the copied file to be the original copy date.

I know about things like rsync and other command line tools that are available to make it possible to copy and retain original file dates. That's not what I want. I have a special case where I have to copy files through a specific channel that isn't rsync or command line capable (at least not easily).

I also know about touch and other utilities for Mac and Windows that will let you manually change the "date created" and "date modified" attributes, or change them in bulk to a single manually entered date. That's not what I want either.

What I am looking for, if one exists, is a utility that lets you sync one date attribute of a file to another date attribute of that same file, ideally by combing through a list of files (in bulk or batch processing) and handling this date change automatically, on each file in that collection. Ideally, if it could be accessible via File Explorer's context menu, that would be phenomenal. If it has to be done by command line, I suppose that could work too. Or maybe the command could be ported to a cmd script that could either be added to the context menu of File Explorer to run it within a given directory, or a standalone cmd file that could be run from within the folder whose contents you wish to update/synchronize file date attributes as described above.

I hope I've described what I'm looking for clearly enough!

Comment: You know of `rsync` but say you are looking for a utility which does what `rsync` does, only it can't be `rsync`.  I don't get what you want.

Comment: Doesn't rsync require the original source files?

Comment: You don't want to copy some files?  You just want to set a timestamp?

Comment: Wait, which kind of "source" files do you mean?  Opposite of "destination" or "computer source code".

Comment: Opposite of destination. I thought I explained pretty clearly that I won't have access to the source files. I only have the copied files in this case. The utility I want would cycle through files in a folder and on each file do this: Set the creation date to the modified date of that same file. Is that clearer? Ideally I want a Windows explorer context menu utility to do this, if possible.

Comment: Ah, I see.  You want to fix the copied file timestamps after the fact.  What about copying the files again?

Comment: Can't. As I said I won't have access to the source files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use attributechanger to do such things. I don't know if it will do batch files but it does integrate with shell. Light weight and nonintrusive. I've installed on it every box I've owned in the past 8 years. Google "romain petges attribute changer"

Comment: Please see [How do I recommend software in my answers?](http://meta.superuser.com/q/5329/354511)